# variables interaction with arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm extreemly new to programing (3rd day) please be kind:p
I've tried to make a pay calculator to cement what i've picked up so far, but have run into a wall when it comes to tax calculation and was hoping that someone would be able to help me figure it out.

I need to compare the var taxBase against the array (bt) below it. i was thinking that i could subtract taxBase from each of the numbers in the array and return the only positive number as a new var to be used later.

```
var taxBase = base * 26;
var bt = [37001,80001,180001];
```

Any help or thoughts on a better way to do it would be greatly apreciated

Comment: *"I need to compare the var taxBase against the array (bt) below it."* Compare how? `<`? `>`? Some calculation (you mentioned subtraction)?

Answer (score 0):

```
var taxBase = base * 26;
var bt = [37001,80001,180001];

if(bt.indexOf(taxBase)!=-1){
  console.log("present");
} else {
  console.log("not present");
}
```

Will return positive if exist if not exist will return -1

Answer (score 0):

> i was thinking that i could subtract `taxBase` from each of the numbers in the array and return the only positive number as a new `var` to be used later.

If subtracting them makes sense (subtraction isn't a "comparison"), yes, you can do that. Here's a very simple way, using a `for` loop:

```
var index, val;
var taxBase = base * 26;
var bt = [37001,80001,180001];
var results = [];
for (index = 0; index < bt.length; ++index) {
    val = bt[index] - taxBase; // Do the subtraction, remember result in `val`
    if (val > 0) {             // Is it positive? (0 is not positive)
        results.push(val);     // Yes, push it on the results array
    }
}
```

Thinking about taxes and what `bt` might represent, it seems like what you really want is to find the first value in `bt` that `taxBase` is *less than*. If so:

```
var index;
var taxBase = base * 26;
var bt = [37001,80001,180001];
var entryToUse;
for (index = 0; index < bt.length; ++index) {
    // Is it less than this entry?
    if (taxBase < bt[index]) {
        // Yes, remember this entry
        entryToUse = bt[index];

        // Stop looping
        break;
    }
}
```

After the above, `entryToUse` will be `37001`, `80001`, `180001`, or `undefined` if `taxBase` is larger than all of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = [];
for(var i = 0;i < bt.length;i++){
  var value = bt[i] - taxBase
  if(value > 0){
    results.push(value);
  }
}
```

Now the array `results` will contain all the positive values.